# How to create c# application setup file with .net framework installation?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, installation, installshield

I have created a C# application, it requires the .NET framework 4.5. I created setup file using setting option publish tab in Visual Studio 2012. Good point is it easily install prerequisite if not available on OS. But I do not like icon and gui of it so I used installshield limited edition. It's gui is good but it does not install prerequisite rather it cancel installation. Is there something I am missing? Or let me know any plugin or vs version that can fulfill my requirement.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using the community or professional edition of visual studio 2012?

Comment: I m using visual studio 2012 ultimate